# How to collect all "sub" dictionary keys?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm storing information read from several files into a dictionary of dictionaries. One piece of information will be guaranteed and should be unique so it is the key for the larger dictionary entry. There are other attributes which are associated to each key entry which are not always determinable. I also do not want have hard coded values in the code to get only certain attributes.

For example, the file I'm parsing has data like so:

```
id=1
length=10
width=11
id=2
width=1
length=4
height=2
id=3
some user defined attribute=making life easy
```

The parsing of the data is trivial and I'm storing each item as a dictionary of the attributes with `id` being used as the key in the larger dictionary. (Multiple files are being pushed into one dictionary.)

What I'm stuck on is how to best get all attributes in order to shove the data out to a csv report file using `csv.DictWriter` so that I can then have something like this:

(pseudo csv formatting)

```
id, length, width, height, 'some user defined attribute',
1, 10, 11, , ,
2, 1, 4, 2, ,
3, , , , making life easy,
```

I think my options are:

1. Collect them as I build the dictionary storing in a list. Except then I need to pass around the list along with the dictionary.
2. <s>Run through the dictionary and build it up after.</s> Inefficient.
3. Alternate to "Collect them", extend the dictionary and add that functionality to it when I add items.

Comment: Option 1 sounds good to me.

Comment: Have you looked at JSON?  It's a seemingly perfect format for storing the type of data you describe.  That seems likely to be a better format for your output than csv.  There are also options for converting from 1 to the other if you need csv.

Comment: JSON wouldn't be bad, however the intent is to provide it to a human consumer to just open in excel or whatever :) I'm also doing some other analytics in Python on the data so not just reformatting the data.